# How to clean up GAE production datastore?

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

Is there any effective way (in terms of number or read/write operations) to:

1. delete all NDB datastore records of particular kind;
2. delete everything in the datastore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ndb.delete_multi(
   MyModel.query().fetch(keys_only=True)
)
```

You need to do this for each model separately.

--OR--

If you have Datastore Admin enabled in your developer console, your can do this directly for all entities of any or all Kinds.

Comment: Thanks. Will usage of Datastore Admin help to save read/write ops?

Comment: I know of no more efficient means.

Comment: No it will not save any ops, and you will have to click and iterate manually only by 200 entities. Cause you might have a lot of entities is safer to fire it in a task queue or mapreduce so you can avoid the `DeadLineExceeded` error.

Comment: I am not talking about deleting entities in the Datastore Viewer.  I am talking about deleting Kinds in the Datastore Admin.  Big difference.

Answer (score 1):

The remote API is great for this sort of operation. See the article below, it even includes an example for deleting all entities of a given kind.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/remote_api